# UIImagePickerController cause memory warning when taking and selecting an image

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm going through a memory issue using a simple "UIImagePickerController".
I get two memory warning: one at when I take the image, and one when I touch on the "Use" button... 
And the best is, this only append on the 4S (which happen to be my boss's phone). I'm not even able to reproduce this bug on an other model of iPhone (tested on a 3G, 3GS, 4 and 5).

I tried different things and this is this is the simplest exemple which is able to reproduce the problem:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

picker.delegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

[picker release];
```

And I implement the delegate methods:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

// should do something with the [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] retain];

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(selectedImage, nil, NULL, nil);

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Does anyone know this issue and hopefully the solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seeing a memory warning while taking a photo is not unusual. Is it causing a problem?

Comment: it may explain the first memory warning but the second one really happend when I click on "use" to select the image.

Comment: Choosing to use the image still takes a some memory to process. Are you asking about this out of curiosity or because it is causing a problem? If it is causing a problem, you need to clarify what that problem is.

Comment: the problem is that I get my viewcontroller released by theses memory warnings (the one which create the image picker)... I find an alternative by retaining this viewcontroller when receiving a memory warning...

Comment: I am having the same problem with many Memory warnings only in iPhone4S. And obviously app crashes. Sometimes app crashes for even 2nd image. Can anybody suggest ways to handle images in order to consume very low memory and especially when dealing with UIImagePickerController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very common. As long as you handle the memory warning without crashing and have enough space to keep going, don't let it drive...